# razor syntax: loop with ifs and divs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, view, razor, if-statement

It's my first post, hence hello :)

I want to conditionally open and close div. What am I doing wrong?

```
@foreach (var m in Model.Recipes)
{
    if (left)
    {
        <div class="rec-line">
    }    

    if (left)
    {            
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you are expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: You can't open and close elements in different blocks like that. What are you trying to accomplish? There might be a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's solved below, but for your curiosity I am listing elements from the collection in pairs. Hence, on every odd element I open div and after even one I close it.
[div]
[left][right]
[/div]
[div]...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the escape character to let the razor engine know that `<div>` is text by using `@:`

code:

```
@foreach (var m in Model.Recipes)
{
if (left)
{
    @:<div class="rec-line">
}    

if (left)
{            
    @:</div>
}
}
```

Comment: No you don't: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Comment: @Shark - Yes you do. Re read your article "`@if (foo) {
  @:Plain Text is @bar
}`". Clearly if you try to compile the op's original code it will have a logical error and display improperly. The fix to this situation is to add in the @: markers so that the html markup does not break the c# statements. To be clear, without @: this will not render, with @: this will render.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that between these ifs I have a lot of code (with js etc.) and I just couldn't figure out what should be escaped! Thanks!

Comment: Also just solved my problem trying to close off a row div every 4 items.